# How to insert both global and local variables inside a string in python

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

I want to create a string where I want to replace both a global and local variable at the same time. The code shown below gives me an error. (KeyError: 'Table')

```
TABLE = my_table
def get_data():
    data_size = 10
    print "get %(data_size)s rows from the table %(TABLE)s" %locals() %globals()
```

I want the code to print the following:

```
get 10 rows from the table my_table
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print "get %s rows from the table %s"%(data_size, TABLE)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it doesn't work for me. I get 
`TypeError: format requires a mapping`

Comment: @PulkitBansal Yeah my bad. The syntax wasn't perfect, but it's something along those lines. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your formatting string exactly as you are now, you'll need to specify the exact mapping as a dictionary like this:

```
mapping = {'data_size' : locals()['data_size'], 'TABLE' : globals()['TABLE']}
```

Or, more simply,

```
mapping = {'data_size' : data_size, 'TABLE' : TABLE}
```

Now, pass the mapping into the string like this:

```
print "get %(data_size)s rows from the table %(TABLE)s" % mapping
```

This'll give you `get 10 rows from the table my_table`.

The `TypeError` you receive is because `%(...)s` expects the same key : value mapping to be specified in the format args passed to the string.

Comment: `locals()['data_size']` and `globals()['TABLE']` can just be written `data_size` and `TABLE`

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, edited. Kept that in initially because it seemed synonymous with OP's goals of using locals()/globals().

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED, this is helpful. I didn't realize that locals() and globals() are basically dictionaries.

Comment: @PulkitBansal Glad to help. Indeed they are. Remember, you can always mark an answer accepted if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to print like this way :

```
TABLE = "my_table"
def get_data():
    data_size = 10
    print "get %s rows from the table %s"%(data_size, TABLE)
```

OUTPUT :

> get 10 rows from the table my_table

Comment: This is a helpful answer. Still is there any way where I can write the variable names data_size and TABLE inside the string? Because as the string becomes long and complicated it becomes difficult to put variables in the correct order.